# Str::endsWith() Laravel - best practice to check multiple cases?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've been using `Str::endsWith` to check a couple of strings and ensure some domains are blocked from signing up to my site.

Just wondered if there was a good way to pass multiple 'checks' to Str::endsWith in Laravel.

```
$result = Str::endsWith($email_address, '@mail.ru');
```

Can I pass an array in as the second argument for it to check multiple extensions for example?

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can pass an array of values as the second argument:

```
/**
 * Determine if a given string ends with a given substring.
 *
 * @param  string  $haystack
 * @param  string|array  $needles
 * @return bool
 */
public static function endsWith($haystack, $needles)
```

You could also have just **tried** and found this out instead of asking. `;-)`

Any question that is in the format of "Can I ..." means you can try and most likely answer yourself.

Always try things, you aren't going to break anything ... most likely.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it clean, you can use Laravel's validator with this.

Since Laravel 5.8.17, the `ends_with` rule was added. So assuming that you are validating the request - you can use it like this:

```php
$request->validate([
    'email' => 'required|ends_with:google.com,laravel.com,domain.com' // You can use more than one here by seperating with commas
]);
```